# Default options in computing the Jacobian in scipy.optimize.root

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

In the documentations for [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.root-lm.html#optimize-root-lm) with `method = lm` the following are the default for `options` keyword.

`options={'col_deriv': 0, 'diag': None, 'factor': 100, 'gtol': 0.0, 'eps': 0.0, 'func': None, 'maxiter': 0, 'xtol': 1.49012e-08, 'ftol': 1.49012e-08}`

On the description for `col_deriv` they say that

`col_deriv : bool, optional
non-zero to specify that the Jacobian function computes derivatives down the columns (faster, because there is no transpose operation)`

If I understand the statement it says that if I write `col_deriv = True` for example, the `jacobian` will be computed column wise and therefore faster.

**Question**: If it is faster, why isn't a non zero value for `col_deriv` the default value?.

Am I missing something here?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the documentation from [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) could help since it documents both `Dfun` (Jacobian) and `col_deriv`. From `Dfun` we get:

> Dfun : callable, optional
>
> A function or method to compute the Jacobian of func **with derivatives across the rows**. If this is None, the Jacobian will be estimated.

From `col_deriv` we get:

> col_deriv : bool, optional
>
> non-zero to specify that *the Jacobian function computes derivatives down the columns* (faster, because there is no transpose operation).

My reading of this is as follows:

1. By default, `scipy` expects that a function that computes the Jacobian matrix return a matrix that follows "normal" definition (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).
2. However, `scipy` itself calls other functions, possibly written in Fortran [see, e.g., minpack](http://www.netlib.org/minpack/), which expect that derivatives (with regard to coordinates) are placed in columns.

It follows that if the function that computes the Jacobian matrix could return a matrix with derivatives placed along columns instead of rows, then `scipy` will not need to transpose the Jacobian matrix before passing it to the `minpack` function thus saving computational time.

Answer (score 2):

The default corresponds to the mathematical convention for writing the Jacobian matrix, as recorded on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) among other places: the first row of the matrix consists of the partial derivatives of the first component of the function, etc. This works better in multivariable calculus, because one can multiply that matrix on the right by the column vector of variables to obtain the linear approximation to the function.

For example, let

```
fun = lambda x: [x[0]**3-x[1], 2*x[0]+x[1]-12]
```

The conventional way of writing the Jacobian would be

```
jac = lambda x: [[3*x[0]**2, -1], [2, 1]]
```

where `[3*x[0]**2, -1]` comes from differentiating the first component of `fun`, `x[0]**3-x[1]`.

The method `root(fun, [0, 0], jac=jac)` converges in 12 iterations. Or we could write the Jacobian in transposed way,

```
jact = lambda x: [[3*x[0]**2, 2], [-1, 1]]
```

and use

```
root(fun, [0, 0], jac=jact, options={"col_deriv": 1})
```

to the same effect. It's not obvious to me that the gain is worth it, but perhaps it is for very large systems.

If `"col_deriv": 1` was the default, there'd be unhappy users who implemented the Jacobian in the way they are used to and found the performance is poor (using an incorrect version of Jacobian in the above example more than doubles the number of steps of root search).